# tikzcd doesn’t work in custom environment

Tags: environments, tikz-cd

I have a document class `test.cls`, in which I have defined a custom environment `myenvironment` using the `environ` package as follows:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myenvironment}{
    \begin{adjustwidth}{10pt}{10pt}
        \BODY
    \end{adjustwidth}
}
```

Now if I try to use `tikz-cd` inside `myenvironment`, it fails, e.g. this gives an error:

```
\begin{myenvironment}
    \[\begin{tikzcd}
        1 \ar[r] \ar[d] & 2 \ar[d] \\
        3 \ar[r] & 4 \\
    \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{myenvironment}
```

On the other hand, if I simply write it like this—that is, I substitute what the environment would do—, everything is fine:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{10pt}{10pt}
    \[\begin{tikzcd}
        1 \ar[r] \ar[d] & 2 \ar[d] \\
        3 \ar[r] & 4 \\
    \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{adjustwidth}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why do you have to collect the contents of `myenvironment`? Isn't LaTeX's `\newenvironment` is enough here?

Comment: Indeed it is enough, I guess I just got too used to the `environ` package to notice. I’ve tried it now and it solves the problem. I still wonder why it doesn’t work with `environ` though.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining why it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be very careful when collecting an environment with `environ`, as this usually brings problems. When `environ` collects its the environment it "freezes" the tokens of the environment. That is, everything will mean what it was when the outer environment was called. This will break every environment that somewhere redefines the category codes of any character (verbatim environments, for example), or that redefine some character.

In this particular case, the meaning of the `&` changes when you enter `tikzcd`. See:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

When \texttt{environ} collects the environment:

{\ttfamily\meaning&}

\bigskip

What \texttt{tikzcd} expects \texttt{\&} to be:

\begin{tikzcd}
\vbox to \textwidth{\ttfamily\meaning&}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

So basically, inside `tikzcd`, `&` means one thing, but when `environ` reads it, it freezes the `alignment tab character &` meaning, so it won't work.

So use `environ` only when you are sure that you need it and you are sure that it won't break anything.

In your case you don't need `environ` at all because you aren't applying any operation to the collected contents, so this:

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}
  {%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{10pt}{10pt}%
  }%
  {%
    \end{adjustwidth}
  }
```

will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because `myenvironment` absorbs the body of the environment as a macro argument; in these cases you have to pass `ampersand replacement=\&` to `tikzcd` and use `\&` instead of `&`, so

```
\begin{myenvironment}
    \[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&
        1 \ar[r] \ar[d] \& 2 \ar[d] \\
        3 \ar[r] \& 4 \\
    \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{myenvironment}
```

However, there's no need for `environ` here:

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{10pt}{10pt}}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}
```

will do as well. And better, actually.

The cargo-cult version would be

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}
  {\adjustwidth{10pt}{10pt}}
  {\endadjustwidth}
```