# tikz-cd inside restatable environment causes a compilation error

Tags: amsthm, tikz-cd, thmtools

I'm trying to include a tikz-cd diagram inside a restatable theorem environment, but this gives me a compilation error. Is there a way to avoid this?

Minimum working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Here's a restatable theorem that compiles:
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{foo}
This is my diagram:
\begin{tikzcd}
A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{restatable}

Here's another restatable theorem that compiles, this time containing an ampersand:
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{bah}
This is my equation:
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{RCL}
 a & = & b
 \end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{restatable}

Here's a restatable theorem that doesn't compile:
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{baz}
This is my diagram:
\begin{tikzcd}
A & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{restatable}

\end{document}
```

The error produced is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.36 \end{restatable}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.36 \end{restatable}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no B in font nullfont!

! Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.36 \end{restatable}

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.36 \end{restatable}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.36 \end{restatable}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I can provide more of the compilation log if that's relevant. Line 36 is the end of the third `restatable` environment. I initially thought the issue was caused by the presence of the ampersand, but the second theorem (with an ampersand in an `IEEEeqnarray*` environment) shows that this isn't the (only) problem.

Comment: You need to pass the option `ampersand replacement=\&` and use `\&` instead of `&` inside `tikzcd`, because you're using it in the argument to another command.

Comment: The problem is basically the same as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456291/4427 because `restatable` is defined through `environ` or similar device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! You need an `ampersand replacement` if you want to pass the `tikzcd` environment with a `&` to a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Here's a restatable theorem that compiles:
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{foo}
This is my diagram:
\begin{tikzcd}
A
\end{tikzcd}
\end{restatable}

Here's another restatable theorem that compiles, this time containing an ampersand:
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{bah}
This is my equation:
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{RCL}
 a & = & b
 \end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{restatable}

Here's a restatable theorem that also compiles after an \texttt{ampersand
replacement}:
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{baz}
This is my diagram:
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
A \& B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{restatable}

\end{document}
```

[image]